# JavaScript file not working in browser, however it does work in codepen

Tags: javascript, html, reference, photoswipe

I am building a webpage that uses a JavaScript application called photo swipe (http://photoswipe.com/).

I cannot get the JavaScript to run in my browser locally.

I have tested this in several different browsers. I have double checked all file names (including capitalization) and locations as referenced in the code. All the files are stored on my computer in the same folder, in the correct format. I have tried clearing the cache. The external libraries required to run the JavaScript are referenced in the files as they are in Code Pen.

It works in Code Pen just fine like so:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJEWEN

Here are the files I am trying to run on the browser locally:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- Core JS file -->
<script src="http://photoswipe.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pswp/dist/photoswipe.min.js"></script>

<!-- UI JS file -->
<script src="http://photoswipe.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pswp/dist/photoswipe-ui-default.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Link to JS document as it is in code-pen, on computer stored in same folder as HTML document-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="document.js"></script>

<!-- Link to main css document as it is in code-pen, on computer stored in same folder as HTML document-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>

<!-- Core CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://photoswipe.s3.amazonaws.com/pswp/dist/photoswipe.css"/>

<!-- Skin CSS file (styling of UI - buttons, caption, etc.)
 In the folder of skin CSS file there are also:
 - .png and .svg icons sprite, 
 - preloader.gif (for browsers that do not support CSS animations) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://photoswipe.s3.amazonaws.com/pswp/dist/default-skin/default-skin.css"/>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="keywords" content="Photo, Web Design">
<meta name="description" content="Examples of ways that photos can be presented online">
<html lang="en-US">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Gallery 1</h2>

<div class="my-simple-gallery" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">



<figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
  <a href="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1043/5186867718_06b2e9e551_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="964x1024">
      <img src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1043/5186867718_06b2e9e551_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
  </a>
  <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 2.1</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
  <a href="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6175/6176698785_7dee72237e_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x683">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6175/6176698785_7dee72237e_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
  </a>
  <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 2.2</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
  <a href="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5023/5578283926_822e5e5791_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x768">
      <img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5023/5578283926_822e5e5791_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
  </a>
  <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 2.3</figcaption>
</figure>


</div>



<!-- Root element of PhotoSwipe. Must have class pswp. -->
<div class="pswp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">

<!-- Background of PhotoSwipe. 
     It's a separate element, as animating opacity is faster than rgba(). -->
<div class="pswp__bg"></div>

<!-- Slides wrapper with overflow:hidden. -->
<div class="pswp__scroll-wrap">

    <!-- Container that holds slides. PhotoSwipe keeps only 3 slides in DOM to save memory. -->
    <!-- don't modify these 3 pswp__item elements, data is added later on. -->
    <div class="pswp__container">
        <div class="pswp__item"></div>
        <div class="pswp__item"></div>
        <div class="pswp__item"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Default (PhotoSwipeUI_Default) interface on top of sliding area. Can be changed. -->
    <div class="pswp__ui pswp__ui--hidden">

        <div class="pswp__top-bar">

            <!--  Controls are self-explanatory. Order can be changed. -->

            <div class="pswp__counter"></div>

            <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--close" title="Close (Esc)"></button>

            <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--share" title="Share">   </button>

            <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--fs" title="Toggle fullscreen"></button>

            <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--zoom" title="Zoom in/out"></button>

            <!-- Preloader demo http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/yyBWoR -->
            <!-- element will get class pswp__preloader--active when preloader is running -->
            <div class="pswp__preloader">
                <div class="pswp__preloader__icn">
                  <div class="pswp__preloader__cut">
                    <div class="pswp__preloader__donut"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="pswp__share-modal pswp__share-modal--hidden pswp__single-tap">
            <div class="pswp__share-tooltip"></div> 
        </div>

        <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--arrow--left" title="Previous (arrow left)">
        </button>

        <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--arrow--right" title="Next (arrow right)">
        </button>

        <div class="pswp__caption">
            <div class="pswp__caption__center"></div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </section>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.my-simple-gallery {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.my-simple-gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.my-simple-gallery figure {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  width: 150px;
}
.my-simple-gallery figcaption {
  display: none;
}

*{margin:0;}

.my-simple-gallery {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
 .my-simple-gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
 .my-simple-gallery figure {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  width: 150px;
 }
.my-simple-gallery figcaption {
  display: none;
 }
```

JavaScript

```
var initPhotoSwipeFromDOM = function(gallerySelector) {

// parse slide data (url, title, size ...) from DOM elements 
// (children of gallerySelector)
var parseThumbnailElements = function(el) {
    var thumbElements = el.childNodes,
        numNodes = thumbElements.length,
        items = [],
        figureEl,
        childElements,
        linkEl,
        size,
        item;

    for(var i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {


        figureEl = thumbElements[i]; // <figure> element

        // include only element nodes 
        if(figureEl.nodeType !== 1) {
            continue;
        }

        linkEl = figureEl.children[0]; // <a> element

        size = linkEl.getAttribute('data-size').split('x');

        // create slide object
        item = {
            src: linkEl.getAttribute('href'),
            w: parseInt(size[0], 10),
            h: parseInt(size[1], 10)
        };



        if(figureEl.children.length > 1) {
            // <figcaption> content
            item.title = figureEl.children[1].innerHTML; 
        }

        if(linkEl.children.length > 0) {
            // <img> thumbnail element, retrieving thumbnail url
            item.msrc = linkEl.children[0].getAttribute('src');
        } 

        item.el = figureEl; // save link to element for getThumbBoundsFn
        items.push(item);
    }

    return items;
};

// find nearest parent element
var closest = function closest(el, fn) {
    return el && ( fn(el) ? el : closest(el.parentNode, fn) );
};

// triggers when user clicks on thumbnail
var onThumbnailsClick = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;

    var eTarget = e.target || e.srcElement;

    var clickedListItem = closest(eTarget, function(el) {
        return (el.tagName && el.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'FIGURE');
    });

    if(!clickedListItem) {
        return;
    }


    // find index of clicked item
    var clickedGallery = clickedListItem.parentNode,
        childNodes = clickedListItem.parentNode.childNodes,
        numChildNodes = childNodes.length,
        nodeIndex = 0,
        index;

    for (var i = 0; i < numChildNodes; i++) {
        if(childNodes[i].nodeType !== 1) { 
            continue; 
        }

        if(childNodes[i] === clickedListItem) {
            index = nodeIndex;
            break;
        }
        nodeIndex++;
    }



    if(index >= 0) {
        openPhotoSwipe( index, clickedGallery );
    }
    return false;
};

// parse picture index and gallery index from URL (#&pid=1&gid=2)
var photoswipeParseHash = function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1),
    params = {};

    if(hash.length < 5) {
        return params;
    }

    var vars = hash.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        if(!vars[i]) {
            continue;
        }
        var pair = vars[i].split('=');  
        if(pair.length < 2) {
            continue;
        }           
        params[pair[0]] = pair[1];
    }

    if(params.gid) {
        params.gid = parseInt(params.gid, 10);
    }

    if(!params.hasOwnProperty('pid')) {
        return params;
    }
    params.pid = parseInt(params.pid, 10);
    return params;
};

var openPhotoSwipe = function(index, galleryElement, disableAnimation) {
    var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0],
        gallery,
        options,
        items;

    items = parseThumbnailElements(galleryElement);

    // define options (if needed)
    options = {
        index: index,

        // define gallery index (for URL)
        galleryUID: galleryElement.getAttribute('data-pswp-uid'),

        getThumbBoundsFn: function(index) {
            // See Options -> getThumbBoundsFn section of docs for more info
            var thumbnail = items[index].el.getElementsByTagName('img')[0],     // find thumbnail
                pageYScroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                rect = thumbnail.getBoundingClientRect(); 

            return {x:rect.left, y:rect.top + pageYScroll, w:rect.width};
        },

        // history & focus options are disabled on CodePen
        // remove these lines in real life: 
       history: false,
       focus: false 

    };

    if(disableAnimation) {
        options.showAnimationDuration = 0;
    }

    // Pass data to PhotoSwipe and initialize it
    gallery = new PhotoSwipe( pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
    gallery.init();
};

// loop through all gallery elements and bind events
var galleryElements = document.querySelectorAll( gallerySelector );

for(var i = 0, l = galleryElements.length; i < l; i++) {
    galleryElements[i].setAttribute('data-pswp-uid', i+1);
    galleryElements[i].onclick = onThumbnailsClick;
}

// Parse URL and open gallery if it contains #&pid=3&gid=1
var hashData = photoswipeParseHash();
if(hashData.pid > 0 && hashData.gid > 0) {
    openPhotoSwipe( hashData.pid - 1 ,  galleryElements[ hashData.gid - 1 ], true );
}
};

// execute above function
initPhotoSwipeFromDOM('.my-simple-gallery');
```

I am stumped. Would really appreciate some guidance to get it working in browser. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: What error is occurring?

Comment: You are trying to eat the pizza before you make it. You reference elements before they are added to the page. You code needs to be at the bottom of the body or called on document ready/window onload.

Comment: hah nice analogy @epascarello

Comment: Haha thanks! Okay so my code needs to be at the bottom of the body. When you say "your code" which part of the code are you referring to exactly?

Comment: @kinso Anything that refers to HTML elements. `var myLib = { myConst: 12 }` would be fine. `var listObj = document.getElementById('listObj')` should be inside a document-ready listener (or, as you might prefer, at the bottom of the body). I personally like keeping scripts in the head, so my preference would be to use `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with when you call the function. You are trying to find the elements before they are rendered to the page. You can call the function at the end of the html document:

```
<script>
    initPhotoSwipeFromDOM('.my-simple-gallery');
</script>
```

Another way to do it is to add to the onload on body tag:

```
<body onload="initPhotoSwipeFromDOM('.my-simple-gallery')">
```

Or set it to the onload function on window:

```
window.onload="initPhotoSwipeFromDOM('.my-simple-gallery');";
```

Comment: I added to the onload on body tag as you suggested:

<body onload="initPhotoSwipeFromDOM('.my-simple-gallery')">

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the link to the js library which i don't see.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Maybe i missed it though.